# css - div's layout as a table

Tags: html, css, alignment, margins

I am having problems with formatting my html 3x3 gallery created with div's. Here is how it looks like now:

http://codepen.io/makkam121/pen/EisKd

```css
.gallery {
  width: auto;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.gallery_row {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  width: auto;
}
.gallery_image {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #BBAABB;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_row">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_row">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_row">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Wilderness_road.jpg/70px-Wilderness_road.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the gallery to align to the center of the page automatically as the number of images in a row may vary. Instead, I am getting a div with a huge right margin reaching to the right edge of the page. And additionally, I want the spacing between the items and the outer border to be equal(they're not...).

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: So `.gallery_row {text-align: center;}` ?

Comment: text-align helped with the alignment to the center of the page but the outer border is still spread to the edges of the page. I would like to have it more compressed - about 10px separated from the items.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgqeJ

```
 .gallery{
  width:auto;
  margin: 0auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid black;

}
.gallery_row{
  margin:2%;
  width:auto;       
}
.gallery_image{
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2% 5% 2% 5%
}
img {
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:20%;
  background-color:#BBAABB;
}
```

Comment: text-align solves center alignment problem, but I would like to have the spacings between items and items around 10px and the same with spacing between items and the outer border, which is now spread to almost maximum with of the page.

Comment: Almost. The only problem left is that "width" in .gallery is set to 100% so it spreads from left to right edge of the page - I would like it to be compressed - the outer border about 10px from the images, so that the main div does not occupy whole width of the page. But I don't also want to set the width to a fixed value, because it will mess up if I add an additional image to row.

Comment: @makkam121- you can change the width, are you expecting these small things to be done also. Amazing